# Scrapy Splash and 504 timeouts

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I use Scrapy with Splash on windows 10 using `VirtualBox` and `Docker`. I've written about half a dozen spiders which have worked but the latest two I've written for different sites are returning a lot of 504 gateway timeouts.

The Splash screen displays properly at `192.168.99.100:8050` and some urls from the text file process correctly if I leave the script running but they are few and far between. Any ideas how I can solve this?

```
#coding=utf-8
import scrapy
import datetime
import urlparse
import os.path
import socket
import urllib2
import collections
import re
import io

from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.http import Request

from properties.items import PropertiesItem
from properties.items import ImageItem
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from time import sleep
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.example.com"]
    start_urls = []
    root_url = 'https://www.example.com'

    products = []
    headings = [] #csv table headers
    product_id = 1

    #custom pipelines
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'properties.pipelines.MyImagesPipeline': 0,
        #'properties.pipelines.PropertiesPipeline': 0 #comment out if use yield itemloader
        }
    }

    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        with open('/home/vagrant/properties/properties/vagrant_syslink/urls.txt') as f:
             self.start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, 
                endpoint='render.html',
                args={'wait': 15}, #, 'lua_source': self.script},
                headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'},
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        ...
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using crawlera with crawlera middleware? I assume you are using proxies since you are sending to render

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't install crawlera as a separate install. Scrapy Splash is not rendering html after javascript at all now. It works via local host webpage but not in Scrapy. I'm trying to reinstall Splash now. Maybe this will solve the 504 time-out issues too.

Comment: I am having the same issue here. No idea what went wrong. Pretty standard setup

Comment: Does it always happen with the same URLs? If so, can you share one of them? Otherwise, can’t you simply retry those requests?